# No browser reads my Google Web font (except google chrome browser)

Tags: html, css, fonts

So i'm using the Roboto font using this 

and obviously font-family: Roboto in my css.
The problem is that only chrome displays the Roboto font. What should I do?
here's my website so you can see: [click](http://www.bestdavnic73.com)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0):

I try it On Firefox 56 and the font in loaded 
 try to load font before another css file may be the problem solved
Like This

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/sshow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: On chrome it looks different than on other browsers. It is thinner on Edge and Firefox, so I supposed that it is not Roboto. I realised that it is, but a thinner one from the font-family. How can I make them look the same?

Comment: the font is the same but font-weight make differents in text  in normal font-weight font is the same but google and firefox  rendering Bold in different way

Comment: How can I make Chrome look the same as Edge and Firefox?